# Replace value in any column in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

In the dataframe below:

```
 T2MN   T2MX   RH2M DFP2M RAIN 
 6.96   9.32  84.27  5.57    - 
 6.31  10.46  -      5.63    - 
  -    10.66  79.38  3.63    - 
 0.79   4.45  94.24  1.85    - 
 1.45   3.99  91.71  1.17    -
```

How do I replace all the `-` with NaN's. I do not want to specify column names since I do not know before hand which column will have `-`

Comment: That looks like the display value for nan

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If those are strings, then your floats are probably also strings.

Assuming your dataframe is `df`, I'd try

```
pd.to_numeric(df.stack(), 'coerce').unstack()
```

---

***Deeper explanation***

Pandas doesn't usually represent missing floats with `'-'`.  Therefore, that `'-'` must be a string.  Thus, the `dtype` of any column with a `'-'` in it, must be `'object'`.  That makes it highly likely that whatever parsed the data, left the floats as string.

***setup***

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

txt = """T2MN   T2MX   RH2M DFP2M RAIN 
 6.96   9.32  84.27  5.57    - 
 6.31  10.46  -      5.63    - 
  -    10.66  79.38  3.63    - 
 0.79   4.45  94.24  1.85    - 
 1.45   3.99  91.71  1.17    - """

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(txt), delim_whitespace=True)
print(df)

   T2MN   T2MX   RH2M  DFP2M RAIN
0  6.96   9.32  84.27   5.57    -
1  6.31  10.46      -   5.63    -
2     -  10.66  79.38   3.63    -
3  0.79   4.45  94.24   1.85    -
4  1.45   3.99  91.71   1.17    -
```

What are the `dtypes`?

```
print(df.dtypes)

T2MN      object
T2MX     float64
RH2M      object
DFP2M    float64
RAIN      object
dtype: object
```

What is the type of the first element?

```
print(type(df.iloc[0, 0]))

<class 'str'>
```

This means that any column with a `'-'` is like a column of strings that look like floats.  You want to use `pd.to_numeric` with parameter `errors='coerce'` to force non-numeric items to `np.nan`.  However, `pd.to_numeric` does not operate on a `pd.DataFrame` so we `stack` and `unstack`.

```
pd.to_numeric(df.stack(), 'coerce').unstack()

   T2MN   T2MX   RH2M  DFP2M  RAIN
0  6.96   9.32  84.27   5.57   NaN
1  6.31  10.46    NaN   5.63   NaN
2   NaN  10.66  79.38   3.63   NaN
3  0.79   4.45  94.24   1.85   NaN
4  1.45   3.99  91.71   1.17   NaN
```

Answer (score 5):

Just `replace()` the string:

```
In [10]: df.replace('-', 'NaN')
Out[10]: 
   T2MN   T2MX   RH2M  DFP2M RAIN
0  6.96   9.32  84.27   5.57  NaN
1  6.31  10.46    NaN   5.63  NaN
2   NaN  10.66  79.38   3.63  NaN
3  0.79   4.45  94.24   1.85  NaN
4  1.45   3.99  91.71   1.17  NaN
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you want the actual `numpy.nan` instead of a string `NaN` as you can use a lot of methods such as `fillna`/`isnull`/`notnull` on the `pandas.Series`/`pandas.DataFrame`

```
import pandas as pd

import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame([['-']*10]*10)

df = df.replace('-',np.nan)
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you were reading this data from CSV/FWF file... If it's true the easiest way to get rid of `'-'` would be to explain Pandas that it's `NaN`'s representation:

```
df = pd.read_csv(filename, na_values=['NaN', 'nan', '-'])
```

Test:

```
In [79]: df
Out[79]:
   T2MN   T2MX   RH2M  DFP2M  RAIN
0  6.96   9.32  84.27   5.57   NaN
1  6.31  10.46    NaN   5.63   NaN
2   NaN  10.66  79.38   3.63   NaN
3  0.79   4.45  94.24   1.85   NaN
4  1.45   3.99  91.71   1.17   NaN

In [80]: df.dtypes
Out[80]:
T2MN     float64
T2MX     float64
RH2M     float64
DFP2M    float64
RAIN     float64
dtype: object
```